# Has anyone started a project similar to Grasshopper (Rhino) for blender?

Tags: modeling, pynodes

For a while now I've been interested in prototyping parametric ways to generate geometry. The nodeview of [Grasshopper](http://www.grasshopper3d.com/photo/mandelbulb?context=featured) reminds me a lot of the nodeviews we have in blender.

I was thinking, with the new pynodes feature maybe somebody has started to do work on node based parametric geometry creation, or does pynodes not make that possible?

**edit**: I'm already able to write scripts that generate parametric geometry  using BMesh API.

**edit2**: example [video of Grasshopper](http://vimeo.com/28175502) in action

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Sverchok

There is such a tool, it is called Sverchok. It's russian for "Cricket" as a sign of respect to Grasshopper. Sverchok is a Blender add-on that works on all platforms, and has over 180 node types.

- The project github page: https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/ (including download links)
- Ask questions on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues)

To get a sense of what people are making with Sverchok checkout the google+ group

- [sverchok community](https://plus.google.com/communities/113245231013159497850)

Comment: At this point Sverchok is the closest thing to Grasshopper for Blender pyNodes. The development versions of Sverchok are worth checking. 50+ nodes done.

Answer (score 4):

Not really.

There have been experimental projects, but nothing too usable from what I've seen (there was some test using PyNodes with BMesh API: [link](https://www.gitorious.org/blender-trunk/addons/trees/geometry_nodes/py/scripts/addons/geometry_nodes)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion writing a script makes more sense. You probably will have to import a few libraries(which I don't think you can do with pynodes). Geometric PyNodes hasn't been officially added yet. It's just experimental add-on at the moment.

You will need to have a fair understanding of scripting and python - whatever the outcome. So if you don't already know python, now is the time to learn.

Here's the link to geometry pynodes if you're interested: https://www.gitorious.org/blender-trunk/addons/trees/geometry_nodes/py/scripts/addons/geometry_nodes

Comment: PyNodes is not only in a development version, its in 2.67 release.

Comment: watch a few Rhino videos and you might change perspective. I imagine maybe a blend of scripting and node combinations would be possible. (i didn't downvote btw)

Comment: @zeffii, OK, I'll check out a few. I know it wasn't you, but I did deserve that downvote for having the wrong information :P

Comment: @zeffii if your interested, I added the geometry pynodes repository to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try sverchock:

- Homepage: http://nikitron.cc.ua/sverchok.html
- Repository: https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/

Here's the description from author's page:

> Sverchok - is parametric tool for an architect, designer, lets you to
>   programm object's form without knowing program longuages.
>
> Breafly, it is node programing of geometry, but in completely virtual
>   way (with ability to bake geometry to blender). You would work with
>   pure data, as floats, matrixes, lists, formulas, etc.
>
> Those who familiar with Houdini or Rhinoceros 3D might know the visual
>   scripting language Grasshopper, which Sverchok has been inspired by.
>   Using a similar node based visual programming principle,
>   Ukrainian/Russian artists Nikita and Alexander trying to bring this
>   functionality to Blender users.
>
> To understand what is parametric in ARCHITECTURE you'd better see my
>   breaf explenation here.