# How to work with a custom Python node in Cycles

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I'm currently trying to create custom nodes for the cycles rendering engine, in python. So far, I can add the node in the node editor with inputs and outputs. What I don't understand is how to set the value of the output, for instance.

This is what I have so far:

```
class OutputColor(Node):
    '''Output Color'''

    bl_idname = "outputcolor"
    bl_label = "Output Color"

    def init(self, context):
        self.inputs.new('NodeSocketColor', 'Color')
        out = self.outputs.new('NodeSocketColor', 'Color')
```

Comment: Tempted to say this is a duplicate because the answer is the same, although the question is different: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/556/pynodes-the-bare-basics