# How to make a wake behind a boat

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

The advanced students in my class are about to animate the dual paddle wheel steamboat 3D model that I gave them.  I'm wondering if it is possible to attach a 'V' shaped wake behind it, perhaps on a different layer, and animate it across the water that they created. I want to be able to position the camera on the stern of the ship and look aft in the animation and also to be able to see the ship from a distance with the wake behind it.

Any help would be appreciated. The photo seen here is a screen capture showing the Planter Steamship on the ocean. It was rendered by one of my best students. Of course this is a preliminary phase.

[image]

Comment: this could be done with dynamic paint

Comment: http://lesterbanks.com/2012/02/creating-dynamic-waves-wakes-using-blenders-dynamic-paint/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

this effect can be achieved using the dynamic paint as in the following setup :

- select the boat and **add dynamic_paint** in **properties->physics** and click **add brush**  ( you may want to use a simple invisible cube instead of the real boat )

[image]

- select the sea and add dynamic paint  and click add canvas with the following settings :

[image]

this the modifiers used for the sea :

[image]

- bake the simulation ,
  this is the result :

[image]

Comment: Any idea on how to add foam in the wake like this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake#mediaviewer/File:Wake_%28Kilwater%29_behind_a_ferry.jpg

Comment: cybrbeast you could map foam texture according to dynamic paint too and then fade it out based on the distance to the ship. See here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/can-i-refer-to-another-objects-properties-from-a-cycles-node-shader-drivers-i