# Model does not impact the the surface to make a wave

Tags: modifiers, fluid-simulation

I have a problem with making the wave after moving object which I imported, it is 'ship.obj'.

I can move object and etc. but I can not make a wave effect described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26596/how-to-make-a-wake-behind-a-boat).

When I use for this an object like cube (add cube) everything works perfect but I don't know why it doesn't work with the imported model.

[image]

Comment: Have you run the animation (alt+A) ?

Comment: Yes, I did. At the same time I can observe waves around cube but no waves around ship.

Comment: unable to diagnostic that without the file. You can upload it here if you want : http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1696" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1696/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wave dynamics are in relation to a Mesh Volume which is why the cube is working. The geometry of the yacht hull are only planes. If you made a mesh with volume it works just fine.

Select the 'Hull-Cube' and press "/" to go into local view. In edit mode press W to remove doubles, which will remove a lot of doubles. Select all the top vertices and press F to fill. The back vertices and fill. Now you have a Mesh Volume.

Happy sailing!

Comment: Yes, that's it. Now it works. Good lesson for me, I owe you a beer ;).