# How to create physically accurate boat moving through water

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation, animation-nodes, dynamic-paint

I am am making a short realistic animation of a sailboat going through the ocean.  I have an ocean modifier with the time animated. I have a plane shrink wrapped to the ocean and the sailboat model has a copy location and rotation to the plane to simulate the “floating” on the ocean.  The issue I am having is making realistic waves trail the boat and the water splashing and pushing on the front of the boat.  I tried the ubiquitous dynamic paint, but for some reason no matter what I do with that it work work.  I want to make it similar to this Houdini made video.  https://vimeo.com/72879742. I know blender just added FLIP fluid sim.  If possible, it there any way with the answer you may provide to make it seamless loop?  Such as to make the sailboat look likes it keeps sailing for ever with no visibility video seams.  If not, it is not a big deal.
Sorry I cant upload the blend file because it is too big.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Related: [How to make a wake behind a boat](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26596/how-to-make-a-wake-behind-a-boat). Haven't tested mantaflow extensively but I personally don't think you can achieve that kind of superior detail with Blender. Even when using houdini it's quite hard to achive that quality and takes a lot of time to understand the principles, layering the simulations, render and comp them.

Answer (score -1):

Well for the animation and the simulation you are looking for, I don't think blender is capable of doing it alone. I am not saying you can't do it in blender, you can but with the help of an add-on. You technically have 2 options. You can go with Flip fluids add-on but I won't say it is good for a project like this. It is good for water simulations, but for foam-like effects, not so much. I would say go with the advanced ocean modifier. It was **created** for these kinds of projects. It is the master at simulating foam and wave-like effects in water. Even though it is developed by just a handful of developers, it will defeat any other water simulation add-on for projects like these. Nevertheless, It is your choice but I would recommend Advanced Ocean Modifier, and it is nearly half the price of flip fluids add-on. Here's the link to both sites:

Advanced Ocean Modifier:
https://blendermarket.com/products/advanced-ocean-modifier?ref=247

Flip fluids Add-on:
https://blendermarket.com/products/flipfluids?ref=247

Hope it helps.

Comment: In blender 2.9, they added FLIP fluid simulation in blender, which negates the need for the FLIP add on.  The other modifier doesn’t exactly solve my problem.  I can make waves and add foam with the dynamic paint, I just have fix the problem I have.  What I am looking for is the displacement of water in the front of the bow of the boat like in the Vimeo video I attached.  The modifier you mentioned did not physically displace the water.  Maybe blender is not capable of it.  But, thanks for the help

Comment: You can always make the ocean ultra big to make it look like it goes on forever. Every video will stop at some point, so you can always create the sea large enough to last till that duration. It isn't like you are gonna let the video be as long as forever.