# Object position not changing in linked object

Tags: materials, node-editor

I'm trying to achieve something like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/can-i-refer-to-another-objects-properties-from-a-cycles-node-shader-drivers-i).

I have the base material like this: [image] which works fine. When I move the Empty using the Armature, the red dot moves.

When I link the collection of the Cylinder in another file, it also looks fine:[image]

However, if I move the linked object, the red dot does NOT follow:[image]

Is there a way to move the linked object in the new file?

Comment: I assume it's due to the shader graph referencing the location in the original blend file.  This might be a place to Append rather than Link, or perhaps just making a local copy of the Empty would be enough.

Comment: What do you mean by making a local copy of the Empty?
I tried appending the collection, but then I was unable to move the cylinder.